# JavaScript Async/Await logic behaving as synchronous

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

If I understood correctly, a function declared with the keyword *async* should return a promise. In the case of the **async3** function, we have 1 billion iterations, which makes the return value take a little longer. Analyzing the code below, what I expected to happen is that, by invoking the **sync1** and **sync2** function, immediately log on the console and, later, the async3 function log would come. However, what I've noticed is that the **sync1** and **sync2** functions only log after **async3** has ended. Wouldn't the **async3** function be supposed to be running on another thread or outside the event loop without blocking the execution of the other functions invoked on the runtime?

```js
function sync1() {
  console.log(1);
}

function sync2() {
  console.log(2);
}

async function async3() {
  let iteration = 0;
  let number = 0;
  while (iteration <= 1000000000) {
    number = iteration;
    iteration++;
  }
  return number;
}

sync1();
sync2();
async3().then((val) => console.log(val));
```

Can you clarify why it behaves like that. What am I missing?

**What I expected:**

```
sync1(); // console logged immediately
sync2(); // console logged immediately
async3().then((val) => console.log(val)); // console logged moments later
```

**What's currently happening:**

```
     sync1(); // console logged after async3 is done 
     sync2(); // console logged after async3 is done
     async3().then((val) => console.log(val)); // console logged after async3 is done
```

Comment: Your code inside async3 is entirely synchronous.  Nodejs runs that Javascript in a single thread so it can't run anything else until that synchronous loop is done.  The `async` keyword does not make synchronous code suddenly be asynchronous.  Your `async3` function runs your loop synchronously, then returns a fulfilled promise.

Comment: Also, `console.log()` has its own issues for when exactly it displays something.  Visually seeing when a log statement shows is not representative of true code flow.  It should be representative of proper order, but not necessarily proper timing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that JavaScript is fundamentally single-threaded.

Although `async3` is async, its operations are *entirely synchronous*, and CPU intensive. The output will only be (visually) printed to the console once the browser has a bit of idle time, but the following block:

```
  while (iteration <= 1000000000) {
    number = iteration;
    iteration++;
  }
```

leaves the browser no idle time until the above calculations are finished.

For `sync1` and `sync2` to log immediately, one solution would be to have `async3` pause every 100,000 iterations (or something), and await a `setTimeout`, thereby giving the browser a chance to do stuff like display stuff to the console, handle other event listeners, render changes, and so on.

Another solution would be to do the computation-heavy `async3` function in a *worker* instead, which is on a separate thread, which won't block the browser's main thread.

Comment: Could he wrap the while operation in another function and await that one `await ()=> { while ... return result}`, or does this have no effect on a an iterative process like while?

Comment: That won't have any effect, because the `while` will still never let up from the main thread. Control flow will only be yielded once the synchronous component of the function finishes *or* once an `await` is encountered.

Comment: It is not true that the CPU is too busy. It is the way JS is working with browser event. setTimeout, setInterval, console.log etc all end up at the queue where the logic is on the stack. After the stack is empty (all functions are called, script is done) the queue will be handled. This is why you see all messages at the "same" time. See the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: @CertainPerformance Let me check If I got this straight. Are you saying that as long as calculations are being made in the client side it will always be blocking the execution of the script thereafter? Where can I find more about that worker (you mentioned) to a separate thread?

Comment: @joaogeraldes If calculations are being done *without* something explicitly asynchronous in the middle (like an `await` or a `setTimeout`), then it will completely block any other JS execution, as well as event handlers, scrolling, (visible) logging, and so on, until the calculations are done. For Web Workers, see MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers