# Why is async function blocking?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the code I'm running:

```
async function sleep(ms) {
    const start = new Date();
    while (new Date() - start < ms) { };
}

const start = new Date();
sleep(5000).then(() => console.log("1!"));
console.log(new Date() - start, "ms");
sleep(5000).then(() => console.log("2!"));
console.log(new Date() - start, "ms");
```

The output I would expect is this:

```
1 ms (or some other small number of ms)
2 ms (or some other small number of ms)
1!
2!
```

Instead what I see is this:

```
5000 ms
10005 ms
1!
2!
```

I'm a bit confused by this. Firstly, why are the two sleep functions not running asynchronously? Why doesn't the second call to sleep start until the first one is finished?
Secondly, if the second call doesn't start until the first is completed, why is `1!` printed before `2!`?

If I change the `sleep(ms)` function to the following, which was suggested in another StackOverflow question, the code works as expected:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
}
```

If I replace `sleep(ms)` with some slow computation without using a timeout, what should I expect?

Comment: because the `while` loop is blocking until a certain amount of milliseconds is over.. if you wait for 5 seconds.. you're blocking the program with an infinite loop for 5 seconds

Comment: See [JavaScript Async/Await logic behaving as synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983435/javascript-async-await-logic-behaving-as-synchronous/63983470#63983470) for some info. Your code within the `async` function is synchronous. An async function does not make synchronous code asynchronous. A `async` function is primarily used for when you need to `await` a thenable(such as a Promise) within your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript isn't really multithreaded. It relies on two things to give that illusion:

- Computers are really really fast and generally complete whatever needs to be done instantaneously as far as a human can tell
- Because they are fast and the world is slow, computers spend a lot of time waiting for something to happen, and can profitably do something else in the meantime

Basically, JavaScript runs a thread until it either finishes, or is waiting for something to happen (e.g. an async network call), at which point JavaScript will switch to another thread, if there is one.

Your first `sleep()` function is a [busy wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). It consumes 100% CPU doing nothing. More importantly, *it never gives another thread a chance to run.* The promise solution does it the JavaScript way: it ends almost immediately (thereby giving other threads a chance to run) and uses `SetTimeout` to regain control (in an async sort of way) when other threads aren't running.

Comment: Is there a full list of non-blocking functions (such as async network calls) somewhere?

Comment: Anything you could use `await` with (returns a promise), or that uses callbacks, would generally count.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the functions marked as `async` are not run concurrently with other code is that `async` does not cause a function to be asynchronous (!). Instead, this keyword marks a function as returning a Promise, and also enables some syntax sugar such as await.

This means that `async` has absolutely nothing to do with Threads, Tasks, or any other concurrency primitives known from other languages. In a JavaScript program, all visible code is executed in a single thread in a blocking fashion, and it runs to completion. This is why the long `while` loop blocks program flow.

Why does `setTimeout` work as expected? Because the code that actually runs is `setTimeout` and the `res` callback, nothing more. In the background, the *event loop* ensures that `res` is called eventually, but the machinery that handles this is hidden from the developer.

Let's look in depth at the first case.

What happens, step by step, is this - note that user code runs to completion in an uninterrupted fashion:

- The first sleep() runs to completion, and its return value's .then() method is called, which enqueues a callback as a so-called *microtask* (which will log `1!`) for the event loop to execute *soon*
- The first console.log runs
- The second sleep() runs to completion, and its return value's .then() method is called, which in turn enqueues another *microtask*
- The second console.log runs
- <The user program is now finished, but there is stuff in the event loop for the JS engine to process!>
- The event loop processes the first microtask: `() => console.log("1!")`
- The event loop processes the second microtask: `() => console.log("2!")`
- <The event loop is now empty - execution is ended>

If you replace the body of the `sleep()` function with setTimeout, you'll notice that `setTimeout` itself is quick to execute - all it does is enqueue something for the event loop to process *later* and return. This is why the flow of execution is not blocked.